# More than three exclusion clauses not firing trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query to track changes in a few tables based on a trigger as we have users that access the database directly and through the front-end. I have written out a trigger that verifies that columns we do not care about do not get touched, but when I add more than three to the if not statement the trigger suddenly stops firing. Is this a limitation in MySQL or am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Here is the ChangesTracker Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Test_Automation`.`ChangesTracker` (
  `tracking_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Operation` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `tracking_query` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL COMMENT '\'\'',
  `tracking_user_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `uuid` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tracking_id`))
COMMENT = 'Table for tracking SQL update and delete statements executed into the database to monitor changes.';
```

Then the trigger itself:

```
/*********************/
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS sample_table_log_update;
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER sample_table_log_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `sample_table`
FOR EACH ROW
    IF NOT ((NEW.excluded <> OLD.excluded) OR (NEW.reserved <> OLD.reserved) OR (NEW.healthy <> OLD.healthy) OR (NEW.router <> OLD.router)) THEN
    BEGIN
    DECLARE original_query VARCHAR(1024);
    SET original_query = (SELECT info FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id = CONNECTION_ID());
    INSERT INTO `ChangesTracker`(`table_name`, `timestamp`, `operation`, `tracking_query`, `tracking_user_id`, `uuid`) VALUES ('sample_table', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Update', original_query, CURRENT_USER, old.uuid);
    END;
    END IF
;
|
```

Comment: Can you make your question into a [mre], so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: But, the most probable cause, if that you should replace `OR` by `AND`, to: `IF NOT ((NEW.excluded <> OLD.excluded) AND (NEW.reserved <> OLD.reserved) AND (NEW.healthy <> OLD.healthy) AND (NEW.router <> OLD.router)) THEN...`

Comment: Replacing OR with AND makes the trigger fire but then it will fire if just the column `reserved` is changed. I am trying to exclude any of these columns from firing the trigger inserting into the tracking table.

Answer (score 1):

Studies have shown that in 98.67% +/- 7.29% of cases this is caused by [a `null` value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html):

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL. [...] Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.

Comparing `null` to anything with `<>` will return `null`, and `IF NOT (null)` is never fulfilled. Since the 4th comparison causes you trouble, I assume that either `NEW.router` or `OLD.router` are `null`.

You can use e.g. the [NULL-safe equal to operator <=>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

> NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

Please note that `<=>` checks for equality (even if it might look similar to `<>`), so e.g. `(NEW.excluded <> OLD.excluded)` would translate to `!(NEW.excluded <=> OLD.excluded)`.